# checkout broken after removing required fields

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

On checkout telephone and region shouldn't be required any more. I set `is_required` in `eav_attribute` to 0. I removed validation in

> Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php.

I removed the `required-attributes` and `required-classes` in the Template

> app\design\frontend\base\default\template\persistent\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml

Now Magento doesn't complain about the missing entries any more, but you can't go on too. If the users tries to go on to the next step Magento doesn't react any more, no JS-errors.

This is Magento `1.9.0.1`.

What can I do to find where Magento fails?

Answer (score 1):

A quick and simple solution is to replace the fields with `input type hidden` fields and filling them with, for example '-' in the `template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`

This will prevent you from editing / rewriting core controllers and models.